# Calculating the two minimum values row-wise and column-wise in parallel?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have been having some problems calculating the smallest two values row-wise and column-wise in parallel. For example, I have the following:

```
foreach(var row in matrix){
    foreach(var col in matrix[row]){
        var value = matrix[row][col];
        if (value < lowestRow[row][0]){
            lowestRow[row][1] = lowestRow[row][0];
            lowestRow[row][0] = value;}
        else if (value < lowestRow[row][1]){
            lowestRow[row][1] = value;}
        if (value < lowestCol[col][0]){
            lowestCol[col][1] = lowestCol[col][0];
            lowestCol[col][0] = value;}
        else if (value < lowestCol[col][1]){
            lowestCol[col][1] = value;}}}
```

Now the code is simple, however if I want to parallelize it, it is very difficult in my opinion. Because suppose I do:

```
Parallel.Foreach(matrix, row => {
        foreach(var col in matrix[row]){
        var value = matrix[row][col];
        if (value < lowestRow[row][0]){
            lowestRow[row][1] = lowestRow[row][0];
            lowestRow[row][0] = value;}
        else if (value < lowestRow[row][1]){
            lowestRow[row][1] = value;}
        if (value < lowestCol[col][0]){
            lowestCol[col][1] = lowestCol[col][0];
            lowestCol[col][0] = value;}
        else if (value < lowestCol[col][1]){
            lowestCol[col][1] = value;}}})
```

I cannot compare the values of the rows because everything happens simultaneously. I can compare the columns though, I think. A trivial solution would be using an additional for loop, but that wouldn't make any sense as it would double the effort.

I have also considered the aggregator pattern, however I do not believe selecting the lowest two values are associative and commutative. Any suggestions how I can make this parallel?

Thanks!

**Update**

I'm sorry I forgot to tell, I want the lowest two values. I have updated my question. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: This isn't a problem that parallelism would be a good fit for.

Comment: Dear Dan-o, I thought so too, but I believe that my skill level in parallelization is insufficient to make that call.

Comment: You could try to break your matrix into parts and parallelize each part. Then you could make a final call for the separate results. It will look a lot like the parallel sorting algorithm. Check this post for some more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter

Answer (score 0):

I think I get your problem, what I don't get is why you do this:

```
 lowestRow[row][1] = lowestRow[row][0];
 lowestRow[row][0] = value;}
```

You have 2 cells or something?, Why does `lowestRow` have 2 indexes?